# Bootstrap dropdown in mobile menu not closing on click

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

in my website which is done in bootstrap, there is a mobile menu, then menu is like below:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="shop_submenu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" data-bs-auto-close="true">
                        Rent Costumes
                      </a>
```

when user clicks on it, it expands and shows the items inside it. When you inspect it you can see a class 'show' is added and when u click it again the class is removed and it should close:

```html
<a class="nav-link show" href="#" id="shop_submenu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" data-bs-auto-close="true">
                        Rent Costumes
                      </a>
```

however its not closing, can anyone please tell me how to close it when user clicks on it again.
this is my live url:
[enter link description here](https://dev.thebrandchimp.com/rent)

, thanks in advance

Comment: I believe "data-bs-toggle" is for BS5. How about changing those data attributes to "data-*"?

Comment: @DylanYi can u please explain using my anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found an alternate solution for this, i used javascript to check even and odd clicks on the button and changed the style of the submenu accordingly, below is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let even = 'block';
  let odd = 'none';
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.style.display === even ? element.style.display = odd : element.style.display = even
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="shop_submenu" onclick="myFunction()" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="true">
                        Rent
                      </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

which version u used.in bootstrap5 we use data-bs-toggle.otherwise its data-toggle.go thru this [https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20dropdown%20menu,actually%20build%20the%20dropdown%20menu](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20dropdown%20menu,actually%20build%20the%20dropdown%20menu).

...

```
                    Rent Costumes
                  </a>
```

i guess you'r using bootstrap4.hope ds helps.https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.